# How to add days to a date while taking into account that some months have different number of days in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, date, printing

I am capturing the date of application "date_application". Once the user enters the "date_application" I am outputting a message to let them know of the timeframe required for payment. Usually this timeframe is 3 months +/- 0.5 months.

The message should normally look like this:
" Please make sure you pay your fees between  `date_application + 105 days`  and `date_application + 135 days`. "

This is what I've done so far:

```
var Date_application= moment('{Date_application}', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var Date_payment_from= Date_application.add(105, 'days');
var Date_payment_to= Date_application.add(135, 'days');

"Please make sure you pay your fees between "+ Date_payment_from.format('DD-MM-YYYY') + "and " + Date_payment_to.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

The problem with this is that it is not accurate, I am adding days without taking into account that some months have 30 days, others have 31 etc... which is resulting in wrong dates. Is there a solution to this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you need to add months, why are you adding days in the first place? How about `add(3, 'months')`?

Comment: Mainly because there is a window frame with lower and upper limits, so it is 3 months - and + 0.5 month, I figured it is easier to use days rather than "0.5 month"